# Using actual road speeds with Graphhopper

Tags: graphhopper

I'm looking into creating an Android routing app that locally saves the actual speeds of driven roads and uses those for weighting.

To do that, my idea would be to save those speeds in a separate database with the edge ids as keys. I'd then have to make sure, though, that importing an updated map doesn't mean that edges get different ids than before.

How would I do that? I.e. ensure that an edge between tower nodes a and b will always get the same edge id upon import?

Or would you recommend a completely different approach?

Comment: show us what have you tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. Still in the process of planning what I have to do and how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge Ids will change for a new import there is currently no way around it. You'll have to either create a mapping from OSM IDs to graphhopper IDs, but still this is error-prone as OSM IDs can change too.

So the best approach would be to store the real position of your speeds and after an import get the specifc edge ids via the location index.